# Does TensorFlow prune away unused components in the computation graph?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensor

Does TensorFlow (non-Eager) optimize away all tensors in the defined computation graph that don't contribute to the loss? I define in my computation graph lots of networks by default, but only one of them is actually used and contributes to the loss, even though others might stem from it or share dependencies. Does TensorFlow handle all that or am I hurting my runtime by defining all of those useless networks?